# 1 Cocoa Window AND 1 SDL Window in same application. Possible?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, sdl

First of I am on Mac OS Mavericks and I use XCode 5.

I'm making a chess application and I use SDL. I now want to have an additional window with some tables and buttons that will show data about the game and control the SDL Window.

Would it be practical and possible to make the control window with Cocoa, or would it be easier to make the control window with SDL as well? Having forms and buttons and tables seems impractical with SDL, but maybe I'm wrong. Performance is very important.

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with the SDL library with C++. I don't think/know if it would even be compatible with iOS development. I would personally use Cocoa for the window and SDL for other stuff if possible.